# How i can stop dialoges in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make html page that contain ads that prompt messages and dialoges like image below that makes redirects and loss original page and loss users

[Example of dialoge](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B223wwxJt6DzakRKaE1kalI3Yjg/view?usp=drivesdk)

I want to stop any prompts or any dialoges on this page

My code is very simple html page with iframe

```
   <iframe src="https://go.pub2srv.com/afu.php?id=1326365" height="500" width="900"></iframe>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question (as text and not as a link).

Comment: So are you creating a page, that hosts these ads? And you want to prevent those ads from generating such alerts?

Comment: I want to show ads without any dialoges or redirects

Comment: @user2314737 its very simple html code with this iframe

   <iframe src="https://go.pub2srv.com/afu.php?id=1326365" height="500" width="900"></iframe>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prevent the iframe from running Javascript by adding a `sandbox` attribute to the `<iframe>` element. Here's how it may look:

```
 <iframe src="https://go.pub2srv.com/afu.php?id=1326365" height="500" width="900" sandbox=""></iframe>
```

You could refer to this page to understand how that works: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

Of course, this is the perfect solution because the iframe might require some privileges, in such case you could add specific privileges that the particular ad requires.

Comment: Very very thanks

This solution not solve the problem

Because the ad dont run because it run by js

But your idea lead me to the solution

I add normal iframe with src js of the ad
Then i add interval with 1000ms that put attribute myiframe.sandbox="";
So the ad loaded and after 1 second js disabled so popup disabled

Many thanks to you

Comment: That's a great idea! Glad to know I could help!